# My Scrollview wont scroll ios

Tags: swift

I have a view and inside of that view i put a scroll view.

I want to make a scrollview inside of view but the problem is if i add label with multiple lines in scrollview but The result is the scrollview will stretch to right not enter to multiple lines but in storyboard the label looks fine when i run it on Simulator the label stretch to right.

My goal is to make the scrollview scrollable without change the size. I already tried to centre horizontal the textfield and the label but the result i cant scroll vertical the scrollview.

I already give this constraint

Scroll View :-

Leading, Trailing, Top and Bottom To SuperView(MainView)

Label :-

Leading, Trailing, Top and Bottom To SuperView(ScrollView)

Leading and trailing To The Scroll View's SuperView (MainView)

[image: The image]

Comment: please share the screenshot for storyboard view also

Answer (score 0):

Put a view inside scroll view,and assign the wanted height to the view also,top= zero,bottom=zero,left,right= to the scroll ,your scroll view wont scroll if everything is being resized according to the phone

Answer (score 0):

Just add "Horizontally in Container" constraint to the label.
If Height constraint was not defined, Leading, Trailing constraints works only after "Horizontally in Container" constraint's added.

Comment: Why? What will this do? Please give more context to your answer.

Comment: If Height constraint was not defined, Leading, Trailing constraints works only after "Horizontally in Container" constraint's added.

Comment: Please update your answer and then I can remove the downvote

Answer (score 0):

Make your label to fit its content by selecting the label and pressing 'Cmd' + '='. So that it will adjust its size as per the contents added. Also make sure to set number of lines to 0 (to wrap the contents).

As I tried with your mentioned constraint and extra is fit content.
Result:
/Users/admin/Desktop/test.png

Hope it helps...!!!